# Angular wrapped uib-dropdown with required attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create custom validation for a Angular form where I'm using the `uib-dropdown` wrapped inside a custom component.
There are several cases where on dropdown changes the content of the second dropdown. In some of this cases the second dropdown has no options, therefore the form should not be able tu submit.

```
<my-select
    options="$ctrl.formModel.myModel()"
    label-field="name"
    ng-model="$ctrl.formModel.mySelectedItem"
    ng-required>
</my-select>
```

Wrapped inside `my-select` it's a custom `uib-dropdown` implementation (mostly adding classes)

Since there's in form element inside `uib-drodown` I'm not being able to validate in a regular way.
Is there a way of validating trough the content of the model?
Also there might be a non `ng-required` implementation of this same component.

Thanks!

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation)

Comment: Yeah... I'm taking a look into that. So far I can see it handles custom validation for form elements and here I have no such thing. Should it be the same? Also the examples uses directives instead of components.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It was a simple uib-dropdown implementation. Still, your link made me end up with a correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my component I ended up doing:

```
self.$onChange = () => {
    if (_.isUndefined(self.model)) {
        return self.ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('required', false);
    } else {
        return self.ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('required', true);
    }
}
```

Setting `$setValidity` to `required` is what I need but it may be changed to anything for validation purposes.

Thanks @georgeawg for pointing me in the right direction!